# What is the proper way to bring this wire up to code and add an outlet?

Tags: electrical, wiring

The previous owner ran this line out of the house. It's obviously not up to code, and I disconnected both ends last fall.  I would like to retrofit a 2 gang gfci outlet below where the wire exits the wall, using the  existing cable run.

Is there an code issue having an outlet so close to the hose bib?

What would be the correct way to enclose the wire between where it exits the house and the outlet box?

[image: situation]
[image: wire]

Comment: Can you read the markings off the cable for us?

Comment: The cable is 14/2 UF.

Comment: Does it have "W/G" and/or something akin to "SUNLIGHT RESISTANT" written on it?  The UL file number on your cable is drawing a blank in UL's database :/

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is:  look up the code in your area.  In some parts of the USA you can't get insurance on your house unless a licenced electrician does the work  -- quite possibly with a construction permit!

If there is no code, then as a minimum I would:

1) get a hammer drill and make a proper sub-ground hole in the foundation large enough for a conduit (personally I'd use 3/4 PVC or similar).

0) Dig your trench and expose the foundation where you want to route the wiring.

2) install the conduit and pull the wiring - make sure the gauge is sufficient for your end needs.

3) seal the conduit where it goes thru the foundation using hydraulic cement.

(yes, you OCD-ers, I know I wrote them in the wrong order)

Comment: Once the wiring is in conduit, you can easily add a weatherproof box, if the OP still wants a GFCI receptacle.

Comment: Why does the conduit need to exit the house below ground level?

Comment: @John again, it may depend on local code.  I just think that since you're going to have to dig a trench anyway, and you're going to have to drill thru the concrete foundation, why not do it right?

Comment: He's trying to put an outlet *on the wall* it seems -- there's no need for a trench here, and it's UF anyway...

Answer (score 0):

The good news -- this is UF cable, so it being left outdoors wasn't a total sin compared to the case if this was NM.  The bad news -- UL's database is drawing a total blank when I try to plug the file number on your cable into it -- and I can't tell from the markings shown if the cable is sunlight resistant (it will say so if it is), so I have to assume for the sake of this answer that it's not.  Also, since we can't tell if the cable has a ground wire or not, we will assume it lacks one for this discussion -- this rules out metal conduit.

From all this, we're left with plastic conduit, either PVC or RTRC.  Given that it's outdoors and exposed against a wall, I'd recommend schedule 80 PVC or RTRC-XW as they are rated for protection against physical damage.  You'll need to have the cable exit the wall into a back-box knockout in a nonmetallic weatherproof "T" box and use a cable-clamp on it as if it was NM, then you can stuff it down your conduit which runs to where you want to put the outlet.  Make sure that your conduit runs are loosely strapped down every 3' (the conduit should freely slide in the strap), with an expansion joint every 12' or so rigidly strapped to the wall to accommodate thermal expansion and contraction -- without that, your conduit run will look like a worm crawling along your wall!  Of course, you'll need another weatherproof box and a while-in-use or "bubble" cover for your GFCI (you can get a weatherproof, nonmetallic FS box quite readily these days).